# Does the following result require the random variables to be independent?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am sitting with the book *Labelled Markov Processes* by Prakash Panangaden, and on page 79 he defines what it means for a set of random variables on a probability space to be independent, and after that he gives the following theorem.

> **Theorem 6.4**
>   Let $\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ be random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space, $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-field, and $P$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{F}$, and let $X$ be the $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued random variable $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. Let the distribution functions be $F_i$ and $F$ respectively. Then
>   $$F(x_1,\dots,x_n) = F_1(x_1)\dots F_n(x_n).$$

Notice however, that this theorem says nothing about $X_1,\dots,X_n$ being independent, which I assume must be an error. The proof is not given in the book, but it seems to me that this result must depend on the random variables being independent. Am I correct in this, and if possible, can someone outline the proof for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a simple counterexample, let $X_1 \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\frac{1}{2})$, $X_2 = X_1$.  Then, defining $X = (X_1, X_2)$, we have
$$F(0,1) = 0 \not= \frac{1}{4} = F_1(0)F_2(1)$$